# How/Where to store data on the client's HTML

Tags: html, compression, client-server

I am storing a skeletal snapshot of the web page that the server generates in the HTML itself, so when i send Ajax requests back to the server, the server can find out what the page the client has looks like and send back the appropiate diffs.

This skeleton is basically a Tree, where each node represents a component (menubar, sidebar, content, comment, whatever) and it's children are it's sub components.

Currently, i am storing it as Base64ed GZiped JSONed data. As pure JSON, it takes about 4000 characters, but encoded it takes ~500. (out of interest, python's Pickle takes ~3000 characters, but only compresses down to ~2000)

So my question is, is there anything else i can do to crunch the data down? Any web-safe data format that is more compact than Base64? Anything compression more compact than GZip? raising the "level" of the gzip function from 6 to 9 resulted in very little (~20 chars) savings.

And the other question is, where should this data go? Currently it's just sitting in the value of a hidden input field somewhere. Does it matter at all whether it's in some input's attributes, some other tag's attributes, as the contents of a div with display:hidden? Or is it not worth caring about?

Answer (score 1):

I dont see a reason for storing it in an hidden field. I wouldnt recommend storing it in the hidden field. You can probably use Jquerys data method to store the json or Just store it in a javascript variable that is scoped correctly.

Well I am not sure what approach you are taking to get the DIFF. Are you sending back the data stored from the client to the server or are you sending data from the server to the client and then  DIFF it on the client end which might be a better option?

Regarding compression I dont think you should concentrate on it too much cos there is a negative too you need to spend time decompressing it. So thus the current thing to check would be

```
compression + decompression < time taken for transfer
```

if thats the case then you should probably compress the data.

Comment: I'm diffing on server and sending the diff down to client. I could do it either way, but i do not like javascript and would like to keep my coding to a minimum =D. I will check the time needed to compress. Perhaps I should just write it into a javascript variable.